# ¿Cómo puedo armar una tabla con elementos seleccionados previamente?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, mvc

les comento mi situación, tengo que armar una tabla pero con caracteristicas de datos que previamente seleccione. Les doy estas imágenes:

IMAGEN 1:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

IMAGEN 2:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo lo que busco hacer es que en la tabla de IMAGEN 2 se arme en base a lo que selecciono en IMAGEN 1. Acá lo que se ve es que en la tabla se me está armando con todo, cuando debería hacerse solo con "Documentos Especiales" y no con "Envío de mails".

Una de las cosas que intenté es pasar los ID de IMAGEN 1, que IMAGEN 2 reciba esos ID con un IMPUT HIDDEN, y hacer un  `foreach` o un `for` recorriendo ese input, pero no funcionó o no sé la logica para hacerlo. el input recibe los ID con un `ViewBag` que le mando desde el controlador.

`<input type="hidden" id="modulosActivos" name="modulosActivos" value="@ViewBag.ModulosActivos" />`

Por JavaScript no sé hacerlo. Es un proyecto usando MVC ASP.NET, HTML, JavaScript y C#.

Éste es el código de la vista en el controlador:

```
 public ActionResult AltaParametros()
       {           
           string parametros = null;
        

           try
           {
               parametros = Session["parametros"] as string;
               datos= new DatosEntities();

               var qav = datos.ParametrosCanalesValores;
               ViewBag.valoresParametros = parametros;
              
               using (datos)
               {
                   return View(qav);
               }                
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
               ViewBag.Title = "Ups, tuvimos un error al cargar las empresas...";
               ViewBag.Description = "Error al cargar las empresas...";
               ViewBag.VerError = ex.Message + "\b" + ex.InnerException.Message;
               return View("Error");
           }
       }
```

Cualquier ayuda me vendría de 10.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Amigo podrias editar tu publicacion y mostrar que intentas en tu codigo o donde tienes el problema. Con solo imagenes y una descripcion breve es dificil ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que querrías hacer deberías de cambiar lo que contiene los campos de la tabla en función de lo que se seleccione en la primera, se debería hacer con JavaScript.
Sería algo así:
1- Seleccionar una opción.
2- Identificar en JS que campo se ha seleccionado y en función de cual sea escribir dentro de la segunda tabla los valores de que se desean y reemplazarlos si se selecciona otra opción.
Sin código ni nada difícilmente podría ayudarte pero espero que te resulte de ayuda.

Comment: Claro, el tema es que no sé cómo hacerlo, y la poca logica que implementaba no me funciona

Comment: Gracias por responder, tu colaboración es bienvenida. Sin embargo, te invito a leer [answer] y a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas un poco más el funcionamiento de Stack Overflow. Tu respuesta parece más un comentario, sería de mucha utilidad que argumentes un poco más tu respuesta, explicando el porqué y cómo solucionar el problema y algún enlace a la documentación oficial. Ojo que sólo un enlace tampoco es un argumento sólido, la idea es que puedas expresar la parte esencial de dicha documentación aquí. Tampoco es recomendable responder preguntas de baja calidad, sin código. Saludos